# Making READ, WRITE and NOTIFY working on Android BLE (version 21 and above)

Tags: android, bluetooth, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my application, I got the **READ** and **WRITE** to work on specific `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` objects. 
The `BluetoothGattCallback` `onCharacteristicWrite` and `onCharacteristicRead` are properly called.
I have then tried to setup the **NOTIFY** option so my Android app gets notified when a specific characteristic on the device changes.
I have set this up via the following code:

```
// Local notifications
mGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(statusTypeCharacteristic, notify);

// Remote notifications
BluetoothGattDescriptor desc = statusTypeCharacteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

Log.d("Descriptor", desc.toString());

boolean test;
test = desc.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);  // return value = true
test = mGatt.writeDescriptor(desc);  // return value = true
```

When the characteristic changes, the callback: `onCharacteristicChanged` is being called as expected

However, now all **READ** and **WRITE** operations do not work anymore.
When I comment the lines dealing with the descriptor, the **READ** and **WRITE** work again.

A part I am very unclear is around the `UUID` used to get the descriptor. Is it correct? Should I scan instead all descriptors from the characteristic and enable notification on one? How do I know which one to set as I have multiple ones coming back?

Comment: thing is, all ble operations are really, asynchronous in nature, you need to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have figured out the issue.
At the beginning of my application, I am configuring (i.e. writing) to lots of descriptors.
2 issues with it:
1- A descriptor can only be written one at a time
2- No read/write operations can happen when a descriptor is being written to

The fix is to create a queue of write descriptor operations and perform the next descriptor write in the onDescriptorWrite callback.

```
private void writeGattDescriptor(BluetoothGattDescriptor d) {
    //put the descriptor into the write queue
    descriptorWriteQueue.add(d);
    //if there is only 1 item in the queue, then write it. If more than 1, we handle asynchronously in the
    // callback
    if(descriptorWriteQueue.size() == 1) {
        mGatt.writeDescriptor(d);
    }
}
```

And then in the callback:

```
@Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite (BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        // Called when the descriptor is updated for notification
        Log.d("onDescriptorWrite", descriptor.getUuid().toString());

        // pop the item that we just finishing writing
        descriptorWriteQueue.remove();

        // if there is more to write, do it!
        if(descriptorWriteQueue.size() > 0) {
            mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptorWriteQueue.element());
        }

        // Inform the framework that the scope has connected, configured and ready to process commands
        if(descriptorWriteQueue.size() == 0) {
            // Do something else, such as reads and writes
        }
    }
```